# Mongoose.model is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers (or comments) helped me.

I am having this error using the exact same code that works in another project and I can't figure out why it's happening.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var objectSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    title: { type: String },
    img: { type: String },
    likes: { type: Number },
    profile: { type: String },
    username: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Object', objectSchema);
```

When I console-log mongoose, it shows this (no model):
[image: console.log(mongoose)]

I've defined mongoose in app.js like follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/objectsdatabase');
```

I've tried both mongoose 4.3.4 and 4.6.0.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Mongoose client-side (in the browser). Support for this [is very minimal](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html),  basically the only thing you can do is declare schema's and validate documents.

Comment: Mmm like @robertklep comments, maybe my answer is invalid... But is valid if you are using mongoose in backend...

Comment: @manuerumx `mongoose.model()` is a valid function server-side, see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html :) A connection isn't a requirement.

Comment: True, true,... i remove my answer in client-side is invalid.

Comment: Oh, that's right! Thank you @robertklep.

Comment: @Hideya did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004659/using-webpack-with-mongoose-mongoose-model-is-not-a-function